# How to get more than 10 items from AWS api ItemSearch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

Is it possible to get more than 10 items per request using Amazon Product Advertising API ItemSearch?

For example we have this link: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=nokia&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Anokia

It shows 24 items per page and I want to get those 24 items all at one api call. Is it possible to do that without any threading and making multiple requests?

Comment: usually there is a default limit on displayed items.
probably 10 is the defualt limit.
just pass a new limit to the api with a bigger number